# Merge data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I want merge data from 4 different query 
so this my query

```
SELECT dinas.dinas_id,dinas_nama, COUNT(sc_user.user_id) as total_user from dinas left JOIN sc_user on dinas.dinas_id=sc_user.dinas_id GROUP by dinas.dinas_id
UNION
SELECT dinas.dinas_id,dinas_nama, COUNT(sc_bidang.bi_id) as total_bidang from dinas left JOIN sc_bidang on dinas.dinas_id=sc_bidang.dinas_id GROUP by dinas.dinas_id
UNION
SELECT dinas.dinas_id,dinas_nama, COUNT(sc_kegiatan.ke_id) as total_kegiatan from dinas left JOIN sc_kegiatan on dinas.dinas_id=sc_kegiatan.dinas_id GROUP by dinas.dinas_id
UNION
SELECT dinas.dinas_id,dinas_nama, COUNT(sc_paket.ke_id) as total_paket from dinas left JOIN sc_kegiatan on dinas.dinas_id=sc_kegiatan.dinas_id left join sc_paket on sc_paket.ke_id=sc_kegiatan.ke_id GROUP by dinas.dinas_id
```

but the results will be like this

[image]

but i want the results like this

```
dinasid | dinas_nama | total_user | total_bidang | total_kegiatan| total_paket
```

maybe someone can help me for merge this data?

this my fiddle
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tgohmvPrFnbNz8VgezbsFA/0

(count) results must be like this
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you fail to get any other accurate answer then you can use subquery to get your desire output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your expresions group by `dinas.dinas_id`, so the sum of the left join ends up like:

```
SELECT dinas.dinas_id,
       dinas_nama,
       COUNT(DISTINCT sc_user.user_id) as total_user,
       COUNT(DISTINCT sc_bidang.bi_id) as total_bidang,
       COUNT(DISTINCT sc_kegiatan.ke_id) as total_kegiatan,
       COUNT(DISTINCT sc_kegiatan.ke_id, sc_paket.pa_id) as total_paket
FROM dinas
LEFT JOIN sc_user on dinas.dinas_id=sc_user.dinas_id
LEFT JOIN sc_bidang on dinas.dinas_id=sc_bidang.dinas_id
LEFT JOIN sc_kegiatan on dinas.dinas_id=sc_kegiatan.dinas_id
LEFT JOIN sc_paket on sc_paket.ke_id=sc_kegiatan.ke_id
GROUP by dinas.dinas_id
```

Comment: the results of (*count) are not as expected.

Comment: i'v edit my question and add fiddle and results if i use single query for testing

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. `total_paket` needs closest re-validation (it is 2 joins) as I think even in you question `COUNT(sc_paket.pa_id) as total_paket` was intended.